# How to get Eloquent relationship in scope

Tags: laravel, scope, product, relation

$this is namespace `App\Models\Product`;

```
protected $fillable = [ 'name', 'slug', 'company_id', 'original_price', 'discount_price', 'code', 'barcode', 'quantity', 'parent_id', 'position', 'status', 'short_description', 'long_description', 'approved', 'auto_approve' ];
```

Code:

```
public function childProducts()   
{ 
  return $this->hasMany(Product::class, 'parent_id', 'id'); 
}
```

My scope

```
public function scopeActive($query) {
  return $query->where('status', 1); 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like:

```php
    public function scopeActive($query)
    {
        return $query->whereHas('childProducts', function($query) {
            $query->where('status', 1);
        });
    }
```

**Update:**
check quantity

```php
    public function scopeActive($query)
    {
        return $query->where('quantity', '>', 0)->whereHas('childProducts', function($query) {
            $query->where('status', 1)->where('quantity', '>', 0);
        });
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much your solution. This is worked. But how can i check parent and child quantity is greater than zero in scope?

Comment: @ElesgerEldarov I just updated the answer. Also vote up and accept the answer if it helped you, thanks.